# Customer's password changing unexpectedly

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account

I am facing an issue, Some of registered customers are unable to login in website, They getting error message

> invalid login or password

and every time there is need to reset password from backend

Any one have suggestion why this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for $customer->setPassword() in community or local directories as a plugin or extension might be using it to set password.

Malacious code might be resetting your customer's password .

Comment: I found in observer in local folder, Commented let's see password should not reseting automatically